# Cannot assign to value: function call returns immutable value ([[String:AnyObject]])

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

why am i getting this error at the line " let postObject = [String:AnyObject] = [ "

> Cannot assign to value: function call returns immutable value

```
    @IBAction func HandleSendButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let postRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("messages").child("\(selectedUser).[“id”]")

    let postObject = [[String:AnyObject]]() = [
        "From": [
            "uid": User.uid,
            "username": User.username,
            "photoURL": User.photoURL.absoluteString
        ],
        "Message": textView.text,
        "timestamp": [".sv":"timestamp"]
        ] as [String:Any]

    postRef.setValue(postObject, withCompletionBlock: { error, ref in
        if error == nil {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            // Handle the error
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This seems overly complex; can you update your question to include a snippet of what your expected Firebase structure should be? As TEXT please, no images.

Comment: The phrase `let postObject = [String:AnyObject] = [ "` or `let postObject = [[String:AnyObject]]() = [` is nonsense, so of course the Swift compiler chokes. Two equal signs in one line? Even a human can’t guess what that could mean.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `= [[String:AnyObject]]()` part:

```
let postObject = [
```

or

```
let postObject: [String: Any] = [
```

Comment: then i get "Unexpected initializer in pattern; did you mean to use '='?"

Comment: and on postRef i get " Argument labels '(_:, withCompletionBlock:)' do not match any available overloads "

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be like this:

```
let postObject: [[String: Any]] = [[
    "From": [
        "uid" : User.uid,
        "username" : User.username,
        "photoURL" : User.photoURL.absoluteString
    ],
    "Message" : textView.text,
    "timestamp" : [".sv" : "timestamp"]
    ]]
```

`let postObject` part declares a constant, `: [[String:AnyObject]]` declares its type (notice that not using `=`), and finally after `=` is the literal object that initializes it.

Comment: Thank u for answer, but then i get an error " Contextual type 'Any' cannot be used with dictionary literal "

Comment: hey Milan, thanks for the update. But when i change the code, i get all kinds of errors on every line. What did you mean by fix right hand side too.

Comment: @akvag what does it say?

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected element type 'Dictionar, Expected expression, Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: @akvag ok, sorry my mistake, it's not `{}` but `[]`, you just missed two outer brackets

Comment: I tried the your updated answer, but then i get " Contextual type 'Any' cannot be used with dictionary literal " at code line "From: [ "

Comment: And i also get  "  Argument labels '(_:, withCompletionBlock:)' do not match any available overloads  " , at postRef

Comment: @akvag what is the type of `postRef` parameter?

Comment: let postRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("questions").child("\(selectedUser).[“id”]")

Comment: @akvag that's the value, I am asking for the type

Comment: how can i find out this? i think its maybe a string?

Comment: so how did you get to that code? did you just guess what is supposed to be there?

Comment: @akvag The Firebase reference you are creating with *"(selectedUser).[“id”]"* is going to be a problem. That would create a string like this */your_firebase/questions/selectedUser/(selectedUser).[“id”]* which contains characters that are not allowed in Firebase keys, and I am pretty sure you don't want a key that looks like *(selectedUser).[“id”]* anyway. Probably a typo?

Comment: Okay thanks Jay!  So how can i get the uid of the selected user? Like this : Storage.storage().reference().child("questions").child("\(selectedUser[“id”] ) ") ??

Comment: @akvag I don't usually encourage adding code in comments but here are two lines; *let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid* and then the next line *let postRef = self.ref.child("questions").child(uid!)*   the *self.ref* part is a class var that points to my Firebase. In  your case you are using Storage() so modify accordingly.

Comment: Okay great, i get what you said now. Thanks!, but do you have a solution to my problem with the "Cannot assign to value: function call returns immutable value" ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues to be addressed.

Let's assume your Firebase looks like this

```
root
  questions
    uid_0
      From:
        photoUrl: "some photoUrl"
        uid: "some userid"
        username: "some username" 
      message: "some message"
      timestamp: "some timestamp"
```

If you want to create a new questions node this will create it in that structure

```
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let postRef = self.ref.child("questions").child(uid!) //self.ref is a class var*

let dict: [String: Any] = ["From":
    ["uid": "some uid",
     "username": "some username",
     "photoUrl": "some url"],
    "message": "some message",
    "timestamp": "some timestamp"
]

postRef.setValue(dict, withCompletionBlock: { error, ref in
    if error == nil {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // Handle the error
    }
})
```

With this, we get the uid and define the reference to where the data is written.

Then the simple use of a dictionary; Firebase uses key: value pairs to store it's data and we define a dictionary to contain a key, which is a String and the values can be a kind of Any.

```
let dict: [String: Any]
```

That allows the first element to be a String: Dictionary, and the second and third elements to be String: String.

*self.ref points to my root Firebase node. Edit to point to yours.

Comment: Thanks for such informative answer! I still get the " Contextual type 'Any' cannot be used with dictionary literal " though.. really frustrating

Comment: @akvag Then you have something else wrong as that code was copied and pasted from a working project. This is Swift 4, Firebase 4 - ensure you are running XCode 9.2 or higher and it's a Swift 4 project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    let postObject: [String: Any] = [
    "From": [
        "uid": User.uid,
        "username": User.username,
        "photoURL": User.photoURL.absoluteString
        ] as [String: Any],
    "Message": textView.text,
    "timestamp": [".sv":"timestamp"]
    ] as [String: Any]
```

The necessary changes are:

- remove the initial "=" and "()"
- replace "[String: AnyObject]" with "[String: Any]"
- cast the "From" dictionary value to "as [String: Any]"

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hello Brian, thanks for the answer. I tried this now, and i now get an error at postRef. The error is: Argument labels '(_:, withCompletionBlock:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: I don't have visibility into the type of postRef, or the signature of the setValue method, can you post that here? Either one of the argument types does not match, or the labels are different. I don't want to be guessing in the dark, but changing the first and last [String: Any] to [String: AnyObject] or to the expected dictionary type for the setValue method, might do the trick.